# Javascript automatic type conversion is causing problems in my iPhone automator script

Tags: javascript, ios, automator

I'm a javascript newbie.  I have a bunch of buttons in my iOS app.  Some of them have letters in their names; others are just named with numbers.  I am trying to write a UI test script.  In the script, I have an array called buttons, which represents an array of UIAElement objects that correspond to UIButtons.

If I do the following, it works great:

```
buttons["clr"].tap();
```

I want this to tap the button with title "clr", and it does.

But I can't find any way to tap the button with title "2".  If I do the following, it does not behave for me:

```
buttons["2"].tap();
```

What happens is that some piece of the system decides to tap the button at index 2 in the array.  That's not the same as the button whose name is 2.

Can anyone explain?  And is there a way to force it to treat my string as a string?  I tried a few variants, and none of them help, e.g.

```
buttons[String(2)].tap();
```

EDIT: naming it something besides 2 would be possible, but awkward.  The app is a calculator, and 2 seems like the right name for the key that does exactly that.  Those names are used to present the app to people with disabilities.  I don't know all the details, but feel that "2" is likely to work out better than "two" in the long run.

In response to the question about how I am populating my array, it is via [Apple's UIAElement class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html).  Specifically, I have an object window, which is also a UIAElement, and I populate it by

```
var buttons=window.buttons();
```

Comment: JavaScript array index *are* strings. Can you name your element something besides `2`?

Comment: How are you populating your array?

Answer (score 1):

The following code solved my problem.  But I'm still interested in the underlying language issue.

```
var twoButton = buttons.firstWithPredicate("name=='2'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a "plain" object rather than an array:

```
var buttons = {};
```

You then read and write properties using the same square bracket syntax as for an array:

```
buttons["2"]
```

JavaScript arrays are a specialised type of object that will treat numeric indices (even when you try to specify them as a string) differently.

Read the following for more info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array